# При отладке из под VS не выводится текст в вызванную из kernel32 консоль, в чем причина?

Tags: c#, .net

P\Invoke:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Вызов:

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
    // Этот блок выполняется, но текст в консоль не выводится
    Console.WriteLine("Console Runned!");
}
```

p.s. VS 2017RC, при вызове не из под VS все работает стабильно. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, по какой-то причине консоль была уже инициализирована ранее. Например, вы уже пытались в нее что-то вывести. Или просто посмотрели в отладчике свойство `Console.Out`.

Для того, чтобы переинициализировать консоль - можно использовать два способа.

Способ первый - вручную:

```
Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandartOutput(), Console.OutputEncoding));
```

Способ второй - сменить кодировку консоли:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding;
```

Comment: Это не помогло. Постараюсь объяснить подробнее. Имеется WinForms приложение, в нем вызывается консоль при помощи p\invoke. Проблема имеет место быть только при запуске\отладке из студии.